# pyTransriber on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, permissions

I downloaded [pyTranscriber-v1.4-linux-installer](https://github.com/raryelcostasouza/pyTranscriber/releases/tag/v1.4-stable) and installed it on Ubuntu 18.04 following this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /opt/pyTranscriber
cp -r app/* /opt/pyTranscriber
chmod +x /opt/pyTranscriber/*
cp shortcut/pytranscriber.desktop /usr/share/applications/
```

pyTransscriber was successfully installed and could be run.  However, whatever button I press in the GUI, the program just quits and nothing can be done with it.

Is there some installation procedure or dependencies that I've missed or did I do something wrong?

Here is the error output I get when running `/opt/pyTranscriber/pyTranscriber`:

```
xxx@xxxxx:/opt/pyTranscriber$ ./pyTranscriber
Gtk-Message: 01:05:52.628: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 01:05:52.629: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.avail/53-monospace-lcd-filter.conf", line 10: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected

(.staticx.prog:4548): Gtk-WARNING **: 01:05:55.418: Could not load a pixbuf from /org/gtk/libgtk/icons/16x16/status/image-missing.png.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
**
Gtk:ERROR:../gtk/gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /org/gtk/libgtk/icons/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../gtk/gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /org/gtk/libgtk/icons/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Please launch application from the terminal using `/opt/pyTranscriber/pyTranscriber` command and then click any button in the interface. Please share the output - add it to the question or upload to pastebin.

Comment: any thoughts on issue with the supplied information?  or, would any further information be needed?